# Change PHP include file onclick?

Tags: php, html

Example of requirements:

Start by displaying `register_form.php`.
When clicking the "Login" link then `register_form.php` must disappear and `login_form.php` must appear.

**index.php :**

```
<?php
if ( isset($_GET['d']) && $_GET['d']=="register") {
} else {
    include('includes/login_form.php');}
?>
<?php
if ( isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p']=="login") {
} else {
    include('includes/register_form.php');}
?>
```

**includes/register_form.php :**

```
REGISTER FORM

<a href="index.php?p=login">Login</a>
```

**includes/login_form.php :**

```
LOGIN FORM

<a href="index.php?d=register">Register</a>
```

I find this way both the includes appear on the index.php. After clicking on one of the links it works ok.

So Ι have to find a way on the index.php page not to display both but only one include.

YT video showing the above code running: https://youtu.be/IfRjrblmC7w

Comment: One thing to note here: while you can use `include()` to include snippets of PHP directly from files, a better way might be to create a php file such as `functions.php` which has those forms wrapped in functions, then you can simply echo the function (ie `echo register_form();`) instead of worrying about including files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a way for there to be a default value. It will also be simpler if you only have one `$_GET` parameter instead of two different ones, and you don't rely on `else` clauses entirely. A neater way to achieve this would be to use a `switch` statement, and to separate the logic of choosing which form is displayed from the code which actually displays it.

e.g.

```
$scr = "";
if (isset($_GET["scr"])) $scr = $_GET["scr"];
  
switch ($scr)
{
    case "reg":
        showRegister();
        break;
    case "log":
        showLogin();
        break;
    default:
        showRegister(); //it will show the register form if no option was selected
}

function showRegister()
{
    //include('includes/register_form.php');
?>
    REGISTER FORM
    <a href="index.php?scr=log">Login</a>
<?php
}

function showLogin()
{
    //include('includes/login_form.php');
?>
    LOGIN FORM
    <a href="index.php?scr=reg">Register</a>
<?php
}
```

Live simulation: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ed191663efcc8dd3252aa4d7eb00d626b07fbc80

N.B. As one comment mentioned, it might be better to use functions to show the form data rather than includes to separate files (or it might not, it depends on your overall design). But I've shown it that way here in any case, so you can also see the change which needs to be made to the hyperlinks in order for this code to work.

Comment: Good, i hope the code is understandable and you can learn from it also, as well as just using it. Please ask if you're unsure how any of it works :-)